# Visio - Can you Change Picture

Tags: microsoft-visio

I've inserted a picture (no problem) and resized this w/i Visio. I'd like to now swap that picture with another picture without changing location and maintain current size. Powerpoint has a "Change picture..." feature.

I didn't see any Commands in the Ribbon to support this capability.

Does Visio support the ability to change a picture (in place)?

Answer (score -2):

If you are only doing this once it is very quick to do manually.

Open the Size & Position window.

Select the image. Note its width, height and X/Y location.

Delete the image.

Insert the new image.

Set its width, height and X/Y location.

Comment: But then you still have to remake all connections to that image with the manual adjustments of every connection as the autoconnect feature usually does not give you the result you want.